# How to smooth the transaction between gifs display in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an interval that runs each seven seconds. Alongside I have two gifs each lasting for seven seconds. I want to display one of the gifs in a div (here it is called face) based on some conditions, let's assume if Time is multiple of 14. The problem is that there is always a blackout (black page) between the transaction.
What I want is a smooth transaction without the black frame.
here is the simplified code:

```js
    const face = document.getElementById('face');
    var  one = "<img src='1.gif'/>";
    var  two = "<img src='2.gif'/>";
    Time = 0;
    function myTimer() {
            Time = Time + 1;
            if (Time%14 ===0){
              console.log("gif one");
              face.innerHTML = one;
            }else{
              console.log("gif two");
              face.innerHTML = two;
            }
    }
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 7000);
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div id="face">  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an easy solution is you insert the `<img src='1.gif'/>` at html and `"<img src='2.gif'/>"` and use  `display:none` or `opacity:0` to hide it and switch it back using `opacity:1` or `display:revert` every 7 seconds.

You have to give browser some time to load the gif you want and it is very hard to really make a technically smooth transaction, but by using opacity: 0 and display:none, the image will be loaded when the page is loading so there will be a smooth transaction.

A problem I have noticed, you said you want to let each gif last for 7 seconds, but then you said the first gif to display only when time is a multiple of 14 which means only 7*14 = 98 seconds it will display gif1, you could change `Time%14 ===0` to `Time%2 ===0` to fixed it.

```js
const face = document.getElementById('face');

    var  one = document.getElementById('img1')
    var  two = document.getElementById('img2')
    Time = 0;
    function myTimer() {
            Time = Time + 1;
            if (Time%14 ===0){
             one.style.opacity = 1
             two.style.opacity =0;
             console.log('gif1')
            }else{
               one.style.opacity = 0;
              two.style.opacity =1;
               console.log('gif2')
            }
    }
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 7000);
```

```css
img{
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
left:20px;
top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div id="face"><img id ='img1' src='1.gif'/>
    <img id='img2' src='2.gif'/></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using opacity and since the start and end of my gifs are similar adding the Timeout function I could have both gifs for the blackout frame; however, the problem is that now the gifs are being displayed at different places and I have no idea why

Comment: @SarinaHoseini, my problem, I forgot to consider css. you could use `position absolute` to solve it because you have two gifs now, the default setting for position is relative and the second gif position will be affected by the first one. Another solution is to use display:none

Comment: @SarinaHoseini, I just updated the code to add extra css code. Check if it works now!

Comment: Thanks a lot I was using #img{} instead of img{}, and therefore was not sure why everything was crazy. Now everything is solved beautifully.

Comment: @SarinaHoseini no problem, remember the #img is for id:)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to James I used style.opacity and solved the issue.
However, it should be noted that just opacity or display could not solve the issue easily and therefore I finalized the code based on James' suggestion as bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Talk</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="face">    
        <img id ='img1' src='1.gif'/>

        <img id= 'img2' src='2.gif'/>
    </div>
    

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const face = document.getElementById('face');
    var  one = document.getElementById('img1')
    var  two = document.getElementById('img2')
    Time = 0;
    function myTimer() {
            Time = Time + 1;
            if (Time%2 ===0){

                one.style.opacity = 1;
                two.style.opacity = 1;
                
                function myTimer2(){
                    two.style.opacity = 0;

                }
                var myVar2 = setTimeout(myTimer2, 500)                
            }else{               
                one.style.opacity = 1;
                two.style.opacity = 1;
                
                function myTimer3(){
                    one.style.opacity = 0;
                }
                var myVar3 = setTimeout(myTimer3, 500)   
            }
    }
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);


  </script>



 
</body>
</html>
```